# GXT Combobox shows prompt in incorrect place

Tags: java, combobox, gxt

I have a GXT grid. One of its columns is combobox. If one of the values in combobox is very long (50 characters in my case), it's value is cuted and if you hover mouse on it the prompt with full name is shown ([picture 1](http://postimg.org/image/7xq29zv49/)).

But if you move mouse to the long value and then fast move it to another value, the prompt is shown but under another value ([picture 2](http://postimg.org/image/xcsmvsmlt/)).

Is there any way to fix this?
 GXT 2.2.5 is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, my decision was to change one line in the template.
Before:

> `'<tpl if="showToolTipFl != null && showToolTipFl == true">',`

After:

```
>  '<tpl for=".">',
```

Now there is a prompt under every element of combobox.